# Getting the element of a pointer pointing to a pointer (c++)

Tags: c++, pointers

This is the code I have written:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
struct working{
    int*pointer;
    int inf;
};

int main()
{
  working one;
  working *two;
  working **three;
  one.inf=5;
  one.pointer=NULL;

  two=&one;
  cout<<two<<endl;
  cout<<two->pointer<<endl;
  cout<<two->inf<<endl;

  three=&two;
  cout<<three<<endl;
  cout<<three->pointer<<endl;

  return 0;
}
```

How can I get the `inf` or `pointer` element from `three` in a similar way as I have done with `two`?
And if possible could you tell me what does `*three=two` do.Why wont it compile if I switch it with `three=&two`?

Comment: "*three=two do.Why wont it compile" - that will compile? But it won't work, and likely crash when run. You should get a compilation warning about it though that might help you understand it - turn on warnings if you don't.

Comment: The arrow operator `->` is a pointer dereference followed by member access. In your example, `two->pointer` is equal to `(*two).pointer`. Now think about that in the context of `three->pointer`.

Comment: This question shows no effort in trying to figuring out how pointers work by yourself, neither to make a try to google "How pointers work in C++"

Answer (score 1):

```
three = &two;
cout << (*three) << endl;
cout << (*three)->pointer << endl;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.